# Can anyone help me identify what some kaomoji mean please?

Tags: meaning

I've started to talking to a new friend in Japan and I can't work out what some of the kaomoji he uses mean :/ I've found lists and lists and lists on the Internet but can't seem to spot some he's used :/

(´｡• ω •｡`)

(°∀° )/

(´°д°`)

(´•̥ ω •̥` )

(｡•́ω•̀｡)

That's all I have rn, thank you so much!

Comment: To whoever voted to close this due to not being about Japanese: these types of emoticons are used almost purely in the context of Japanese text, and have linguistic meaning, so it seems on-topic to me. Especially since we’ve had questions about (笑) or ‘wwwww’ be considered on-topic, this seems like pretty much the same sort of thing.

Answer (score 4):

Japanese people have invented [tons of emoticons](http://kaomoji.ru/en/), but the ones you have listed were popularized among the users of [2ch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2channel) more than 20 years ago. They are collectively called 2ch系顔文字. They were super-popular in the past but they may look rather outdated today.

[image]

> (´｡• ω •｡`)
>   (｡•́ω•̀｡)

These are variations of [**ショボーン**](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%28%CC%81%E3%83%BB%CF%89%E3%83%BB%60%29), which was named after the onomatopoeia [しょぼん](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%BC%E3%82%93). It basically expresses a disappointed face (or sometimes an innocent gaze). `ω` is a mouth, `´` and `` ` `` are eyebrows, `｡` is a cheek.

> (´•̥ ω •̥` )

A variation of ショボーン with teardrops.

> (°∀° )/

This one is a variation of **キター**, named after 来た ("Here it comes"). It refers to an excited, energetic face. `°` refers to a widely-open eye, `∀` is an open mouth, and the slash `/` refers to the person's raised arm. So this one is like "Hey", "Yes", "Look at me", "Got it", "Come on", etc.

> (´°д°`)

This is a variation of **ゴルァ** named after [コラ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%93%E3%82%89). This `д` refers to the mouth of an angry person, similar to [this](https://emojipedia.org/mozilla/firefox-os-2.5/angry-face/).